# Convert varchar in format mon-yy to datetime in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime

Is there a simple way to convert a date stored in a varchar in the format mon-yy (e.g. "Feb-09") to a datetime which will convert any invalid values to null.

I'm currently using string manipulation combined with a case statement but it's rather cumbersome.

Comment: What kind of invalid values could there be?

Comment: All sorts of rubbish really. I can filter out the invalid entries easily enough though. One example is "Reinstated November 2007" ...

Comment: I'd give you the usual rant about storing as DateTime in the first place, but I suspect you already know that it's your predecessor who did it wrong.

Comment: Lol, that feels familiar. ;) Perhaps a LIKE '___-[0-9][0-9]' is useful?

Comment: @Joel Coehohoorn
Yes you suspected right, I'm working with data imported from a MS Works 'database'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For valid values you can just put a day on it and it's a complete date:

```
convert(datetime,'01-' + 'Feb-09',120)
```

Comment: Perfect! Nice and simple, just how I like it!

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly!
My case I had to get the next month ... so had to convert and then add one month with the dateAdd.

where convert(datetime,'01-' + MonthCol,103) = dateAdd(month,1,convert(datetime,'01-' + MonthCol,103))

Answer (score 2):

This will do it.

```
SELECT convert(datetime,'01-' + 'Feb-09',120)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CONVERT( DATETIME, "Feb-09", 64, 7 )
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me :( I've tried the following:
    select convert(datetime, MyFieldName, 64, 7)
    from MyTable